# to jam ssh on my system (specifically solaris)

Tags: ssh, solaris

I am trying to test a scenario, where I want the 'ssh' from a system stop responding.
I am testing it on a Solaris System and it is easy by just stopping SSH service on the host but my goal is actually to stop the SSH responding to any request.

Any elegant way to do that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Simulate a lost connection?  A non-responsive server?  Because stopping the SSH service certainly does prevent SSH from responding to any request, and it's probably the most elegant way.

Comment: A non-responsive server will be the correct scenario

Comment: After you've already logged in?  You can run `pstop PID` in the SSH process you want to stop.  There will be multiple `sshd` processes.  Be careful, though, if you don't have physical access to the server and you stop the wrong process, you won't be able to log back in.  From the login shell you want to stop, you can enter `ptree $$` to get the process tree of your shell - there will be three `sshd` processes listed - the daemon and two children used for your login. Stop the one that's your shell's parent. If you have physical access to the server, you can just unplug the network cable(s).

Comment: thanks Andrew, that helped !